# C# Get Parent folder name from subfolder ID in Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I got SubFolder ID with which I want to get its Parent Folder name in Google Drive.  I tried searching on Google for long time but didn't get anywhere.  I tried with the code (see below) but its not working.  Please can anyone help?

```
public string GetFolderName(DriveService service, string folderID)
    {
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
        request.Q = "'" + folderID + "' mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = 'My_Folder_name'";
        FileList files = request.Execute();
        return files.Items[0].Title;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get to get the metadata for `folderId`. Include `fields=parents` which will return a list of all the subfolder's parents (there can be many - see [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive)).

Once you have the parent(s) id's, you can use the same get with `fields=name` to get their names.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**`Parents: list`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list)

> Lists a file's parents.

This will return :

```
{
  "kind": "drive#parentList",
  "etag": etag,
  "selfLink": string,
  "items": [
    parents Resource
  ]
}
```

Once you get the fileID of the Parent, you can now request to get the file name of the folder. As stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30057332/5995040), parents resource doesn't contain the title of the fileID and will have to create a multiple request.

Hope this helps.